# iTerm2 "send text at start" is displaying once at start and then executing again in zsh

Tags: shell, command, zsh, startup, iterm2

[iTerm2 zsh session starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGI1Z.png)

The above image shows the representation of the problem.
I use zsh with ohmyzsh and starship.
I disabled ohmyzsh and starship and still i got the same result.

Even though I presented iTerm2 here I get this behavior in vscode terminal and mac terminal too depending on whether there is a startup text or command initiated with the respective programs.

This is my .zprofile

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
export PATH
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

and this is part of .zshrc

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv" 
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" 
eval "$(pyenv init --path)" 
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"
```

I've also commented out etc/zshrc and etc/zprofile in speculation of them interfering. and they were unsuccessful too.

What would be the problem and how can I resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You instruct your console to enter for you the command `Hi` when it opens a new tab, and it diligently does what you told it to do. However, you don't have an executable named `Hi` in your PATH, and that's why you get that error message. For an experiment, replace the _Send text at start_ by `echo Get me some free beer`.

Comment: @user1934428 **Thanks** for the reply. Yes you are right about the error part. **My actual question here is why is it executing (or printed) twice in the console** once just as a text and then as a command execution. As you can see in the following image also the command you mentioned is printed at first and then executed the second time [**Image**](https://i.imgur.com/xiPbUz0.png). Sorry for the long reply. Hope you understood my problem.

Comment: It isn't. According to your screenshot, the command is executed only once. The reason why you see it displayed twice is due to "type-ahead": Assume that you have a shell which takes long time for getting started, and you start typing before you get the command prompt. Depending on the terminal, you will see an echo what you are typing before you get a prompt (the echoing is done by the terminal program), and then - after the shell reads its input buffer -, the shell echoes it again.

Comment: You can see the same effect inside the shell, if you do a `sleep 8`, and then immediately type `Hi` followed by ENTER. You will immediately see _Hi_ being echoed, and when the sleep is over, you see the string again (being fed into the shell) and the error message from it.

Comment: Many thanks @user1934428 for taking the time to reply. You are right about the one time execution of the command. I was just curious about whether there is a way to stop the "type_ahead" you mentioned from being echoed into the shell when the shell actually starts. You said it was the behavior of some terminal programs. Is it modifiable in this case for iTerm2.

Comment: I don't know iTerm2 well enough, and thinking of it, I don't even know whether this is related to the shell itself or the input method (in the case of bash this would be _readline_, and if there is a way to influence this, would be to set it in ~/.inputrc). Of course you can turn off echoing completely (with `stty -echo`) , but I don't think that this would make you happy. In any case, I think that your problem is better asked at [su]. If you explain the problem there using the `sleep` instead of _iTerm2_, it's prehaps better to understand.